# D3: Translation of x axis not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, zooming, axis

I am implementing a bar chart with scrolling along the x axis in D3. I wrote my zoom function and my zoom behaviour, but whenever I try to pan along my chart the values on my x axis just disappear. Does anyone have any ideas why?

Here is my code:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                .scaleExtent([1, 1])
                .x(x)
                .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
        console.log("Entered zoom function!!!");
    var t = zoom.translate(),
    tx = t[0],
    ty = t[1];

    tx = Math.min(tx, 0);
    tx = Math.max(tx, w - d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.ppm_value; }));
    zoom.translate([tx, ty]);
    chart.select(".x.axis")
        .call(xAxis);
    bars.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate[0] + ',0) '
                                + 'scale(' + d3.event.scale + ',1)');

}
```

I can't figure out what am I missing. Could somebody help me?
Thanks in advance!

```js
//holds the data 
        var data =  [  {"yy":12,"mm":01,ppm_value:90000},           {"yy":11,"mm":02,ppm_value:50000}];

        //formats the date
        var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
        
        //define margins, height and width
        var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 30,
                bottom: 30,
                left: 40
            },
            w = 4000 - margin.left - margin.right,
            h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
        var x = d3.time.scale()
         .range([0, w]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([h, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(60)
         .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m.%Y"));

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");
        
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
               .scaleExtent([1, 1])
               .x(x)
               //.xExtent([d3.min(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.date); }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.date); })])
               .on("zoom", zoomed);

        //create the svg 
        var chart = d3.select("#testChart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
         .call(zoom);
        
        var rect = chart.append("rect")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("pointer-events", "all");

        //loops through data
        data.forEach(function (d) {
         //coerce to number
         d.ppm_value = +d.ppm_value;
         d.yy = +d.yy;
         d.mm = +d.mm;
         d.date = new Date("20" + d.yy + "/" +d.mm);
         var dateTick = format(d.date);
         d.date = dateTick;
         console.log(d.ppm_value);
        });
        
        //map values onto x axis
         x.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.date); }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.date); })])
        
         //map values onto y axis
         y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.ppm_value; })]);

        chart.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
            .call(xAxis)

        chart.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

        var bars = chart.append("g")
            .attr("class", "chartobjects");

        bars.selectAll(".rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "rectBar")
            .on("click",hello)
            .attr('x', function(d) {
             console.log(d.date);
                return x(new Date(d.date));
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return y(d.ppm_value);
                console.log(d.ppm_value);
            })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return h - y(d.ppm_value);
            })
            .attr("width", 15)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return d.ppm_value > 35000 ? "blue" : "red"
            });

        function hello() {
            alert("Hello world!!");
        }

        function zoomed() {
         console.log("Entered zoom function!!!");
         var t = zoom.translate(),
              tx = t[0],
              ty = t[1];

          tx = Math.min(tx, 0);
          tx = Math.max(tx, w - d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.ppm_value; }));
          zoom.translate([tx, ty]);
          chart.select(".x.axis")
            .call(xAxis);
          
          bars.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate[0] + ',0) '
            + 'scale(' + d3.event.scale + ',1)');
          
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.1.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Panel -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Test chart done in D3
            </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <!-- <div style="overflow: scroll;"> -->
     <div id="testChart">
    <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please refrain from opening duplicate questions.  If your question goes unanswered, chances are it's not detailed enough to be answered.  For instance, with this question, you haven't included enough code for anyone to reproduce the problem.  A run-able stack snippet, plunker or jsfiddle would really help.

Comment: I added a runable snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `.x` of your zoom function after you set the initial `.domain`.  I'd also recommend that you don't jump back and forth between treating your x values as `string` and `date`.  Make them dates and go with it:

```
//map values onto x axis
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
zoom.x(x);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.1.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Panel -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          Test chart done in D3
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <!-- <div style="overflow: scroll;"> -->
          <div id="testChart">
            <!-- </div> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    //holds the data 
    var data = [{
      "yy": 12,
      "mm": 01,
      ppm_value: 90000
    }, {
      "yy": 11,
      "mm": 02,
      ppm_value: 50000
    }];

    //formats the date
    var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

    //define margins, height and width
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      w = 4000 - margin.left - margin.right,
      h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, w]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([h, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(60)
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m.%Y"));

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 1])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    //create the svg 
    var chart = d3.select("#testChart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);

    var rect = chart.append("rect")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all");

    //loops through data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      //coerce to number
      d.ppm_value = +d.ppm_value;
      d.yy = +d.yy;
      d.mm = +d.mm;
      d.date = new Date("20" + d.yy + "/" + d.mm);
      //var dateTick = format(d.date);
      //d.date = dateTick;
      //console.log(d.ppm_value);
    });

    //map values onto x axis
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));
    zoom.x(x);

    //map values onto y axis
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.ppm_value;
    })]);

    chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

    chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

    var bars = chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "chartobjects");

    bars.selectAll(".rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "rectBar")
      .on("click", hello)
      .attr('x', function(d) {
        console.log(d.date);
        return x(new Date(d.date));
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.ppm_value);
        console.log(d.ppm_value);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return h - y(d.ppm_value);
      })
      .attr("width", 15)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.ppm_value > 35000 ? "blue" : "red"
      });

    function hello() {
      alert("Hello world!!");
    }

    function zoomed() {
      console.log("Entered zoom function!!!");
      var t = zoom.translate(),
        tx = t[0],
        ty = t[1];

      tx = Math.min(tx, 0);
      tx = Math.max(tx, w - d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.ppm_value;
      }));
      zoom.translate([tx, ty]);
      
      console.log(x.domain())
      
      chart.select(".x.axis")
        .call(xAxis);

      bars.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate[0] + ',0) ' + 'scale(' + d3.event.scale + ',1)');

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how can I set limits for my x axis on panning ? When I scroll to the right my values are going and they never stop. And also when I am scrolling to the left I do not want by bar charts to move and get redrawn.

Comment: @blaa, you need to introduce [pan limits](http://bl.ocks.org/garrilla/11280861).  BTW, d3 version 4 changes the zoom behavior significantly.  You might want to think of switching over as these things become much easier.

Comment: tx = Math.max(tx, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.date;
      })); . This line of code shouldn't represint the upper limit on panning ?